# Usage and omission of "any" with a plural noun in a negative sentence

Tags: determiners

Is it grammatically necessary to use ***any*** in the following sentence? Can I omit ***any*** in exams and formal writings in similar sentences and contexts?

> Yesterday was mothers' day but I did not post ***(any)*** photos with my mother on social media. I think importance of my mother to my life cannot be described by just clicking pictures or posting them on social sites on mother's day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I did not post photos with my mother on social media.

This focuses on "photos" as a type or category, and leaves open the possibility that you may have posted something other than photos instead, or done something else entirely other than posting anything.

> I did not post any photos with my mother on social media.

This focuses on "photos" as an actual "thing" and is how you normally would answer "How many photos did you post?" or "Did you post any photos?"

Answer (score 1):

You can leave out "any" quantifying a plural noun, which is not grammatically incorrect.
It is, however, advisable to insert "any" there to make it clearer.